# Column equivalence, including on NULL value

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a better way to do the following to get equivalence?

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE
  ((accepted_imdb_url = imdb_url) OR (imdb_url IS NULL and accepted_imdb_url IS NULL))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard SQL answer would be to use `a IS DISTINCT FROM b` / `a IS NOT DISTINCT FROM b`. However, MySQL doesn't support that. MySQL does support its own invention that achieves the same effect: the [`<=>`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) operator.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE accepted_imdb_url <=> imdb_url
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE COALESCE(accepted_imdb_url, '#') = COALESCE(imdb_url, '#')
```

If both fields are not `NULL` then the above `WHERE` clause boils down to:

```
WHERE accepted_imdb_url = imdb_url
```

If both fields are `NULL` then `WHERE` clause becomes:

```
WHERE '#' = '#'
```

If only one is `NULL` then `WHERE` is equivalent to:

```
WHERE accepted_imdb_url = '#'
```

OR

```
WHERE '#' = imdb_url
```

Hence, if url fields are of type `VARCHAR` and none of these fields can be equal to `#`, the suggested `WHERE` clause is equivalent to the clause of the OP.

Comment: This will also select records where `imdb_url = 0 AND accepted_imdb_url IS NULL` (or vice versa), which may or may not be a problem, but should be mentioned in your answer. Also, given those field names, I don't think they'll be of numeric type.

Comment: @hvd Thanks for your valuable remarks. I have accordingly edited my answer.

Comment: Looks good to me, just a typo left now: if only one is `NULL`, the `WHERE` is equivalent to `WHERE '#' = imdb_url`, not `WHERE '#' = NULL`. :)